# CKEDITOR replacing the span tag with the font

Tags: ckeditor

Using a version 3 ckeditor I have problems copying and pasting replacing the span tag with the font tag as I can fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please upgrade your editor because version 3 is no longer developed and doesn't work in browsers like IE11 and Egde.

Once editor is upgraded, you can replace span tag with font tag by: removing Font plugin  and extending ACF with `font` tag plus its attributes like `face`, `size` and `align`.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraAllowedContent : 'font[face,size,align] ',
    removePlugins : 'font'
});
```

Links which might help in upgrade process:

- https://sdk.ckeditor.com/
- https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide

ACF links:

- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter-method-addTransformations
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent

Answer (score 0):

Angelo

You can check this page https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf

Probably you should add to your CKEditor configuration something like

`config.extraAllowedContent = 'span[*]{*};'`

This will allowed span tag with all attribute and css property